# Installing packages on Tex Live 2011 (Mac)

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, mactex

I have Tex Live 2011, and I'd like to install the `longtable` package. But I have a few problems:

1. Where do I get the packages? Is there a database with all the packages, somewhere?
2. Is there a guide on how to install packages for Tex Live 2011?
3. I noticed many have the `texmf` folder, but I don't... Does this depends on my version being newer than the ones I read about?

Comment: Sorry for asking 3 different questions but I think they all belong to the same topic. If you think they should be split, please let me know.

Comment: It's poosible to install the real TL2011 on a mac but the recommended distribution is MacTeX. MacTeX is globally the same distribution than TL but adapted to the mac. The best way is to choose the complete distribution, in this case all the packages are inside but you can manage packages with Tex Live Utility (it's the version of tlmgr for the mac. You can also install a minimal mactex distribution and the you add packages with the utility tool. For the texmf folder, you need to create it on your library folder inside your home.

Comment: Do you have MacTeX or 'vanilla' TeX Live? MacTeX adds some extra tools onto TeX Live, including a graphical package manager.

Comment: @Altermundus I'm pretty sure a local texmf is automatically created inside `~/Library`.

Comment: @Joseph  it's really easy to see if the texmf is in the library but I always have this folder (it's the same during 10 years, I think for me) so I'm not sure if a local texmf is automatically created inside ~/Library.

Comment: @JosephWright How do I check that? Eheh... I installed it using [MacTex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/) but under my preferences pane I see "TexLive 2011".

Comment: If you installed MacTeX with the normal (full) installer, then you already have `longtable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX Live has a package manager (aka *TeX Live Manager* or `tlmgr`) to install most free packages. [longtable](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) is a free package and (you can see this at the link) there's a corresponding TeX Live package. So you can install `longtable` simply via the TeX Live Manager.

And if you've done a complete TeX Live installation, `longtable` should already be installed.

Have a look at the [mactex-wiki](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php/TeX_Live_Manager) for more information about the TeX Live Manager.

And there's an additional, special Mac OS X graphical interface to `tlmrgr` called [TeX Live Utility](https://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/), aka `mactlmgr`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look and let you know as soon as possible. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: Schweinebacke is right that `longtable` is (should be) available via tlmgr / TeX Live Utility but I like to add that the users `texmf` folder isn’t created automatically, so you have to set it up yourself. To get the right place type `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
` to your terminal. It should point on `/Users/<YOU>/Library/texmf`.

Comment: Sorry for the very late feedback! This is it. :) +1 and accepted!