# How to install TikZ for LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need urgent help to install `hf-tikz` on my Mac. It used to work before I upgrade to OS X 10.9 but it doesn't work now. The error message is

```
 LaTeX Error: File `hf-tikz.sty' not found.
```

I have download and put `hf-tikz.sty` in the directory that I think it is the right path but it still gives me the same error. I have a presentation tomorrow! `:(`

Comment: How did you install LaTeX on your mac? This would help all of us to give you a good answer...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is adding the package using the [package manager](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35734/) of TeX Live if you have.
You might also want to look at [How to install a latex package in MacOS TeXLive?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/).

Comment: Though the question was for TeX Live: With MiKTeX  it’s the same.

Comment: No, it was just an addition for other readers (every one can read all comments).